# How to set function for state using react-hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using class component and I want to switch to function component(use hooks). When I use class component and click on row of the grid, the modal will display. When I use function component with hooks, it show error "modal is not a function"

```
class MyGrid extends Component {
  state = {
    loading: false,
    rowData: [],
    columnDefs: [{headerName: 'Title', field: 'title'}, {headerName: 'Count', field: 'count'}],
    modal: null
  }

  //event click on row
  onRowSelected = (lol) => {    
     this.state.modal(lol)
  }

  render(){
    return (
        <>
          <Modal
            getOnOpen={callback => this.setState({modal: callback})}
          />
          <div style={{ height: '500px' }}>
            <Grid
              columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
              rowData={this.state.rowData}
              onGridReady={params => {
              params.api.sizeColumnsToFit()
              }}
              onRowSelected={this.onRowSelected}
            />
          </div>
       </>
    )
  }
}


export default MyGrid
```

And my function component. It's error

```
function MyGrid(props) {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(null)
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([])
  const columnDefs = [{headerName: 'Title', field: 'title'}, {headerName: 'Count', field: 'count'}]

  //event click on row
  function onRowSelected(lol){    
     modal(lol)
  }
    return (
        <>
          <Modal
            getOnOpen={callback => setModal(callback)}
          />
          <div style={{ height: '500px' }}>
            <Grid
              columnDefs={columnDefs}
              rowData={rowData}
              onGridReady={params => {
              params.api.sizeColumnsToFit()
              }}
              onRowSelected={onRowSelected}
            />
          </div>
       </>
    )
}


export default MyGrid
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

this code. Modal is null

```
  function onRowSelected(lol){    
     modal(lol)
  }
```

convert to this

```
function onRowSelected(lol){    
     setModal(lol)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I try it but not working. getOnOpen props is a function with data is lol

Comment: I need convert from this.state.modal(lol) (class component) to function component